# Talend :tS3Put gives access denied error

Tags: talend

I am trying to upload a list of files from a folder into an Amazon S3 folder.
I am able to manually upload files on the folder.But when I run  the job which does the same thing ,the talend job gives an "Access Denied" error.

I have the required keys for the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the Access Denied error then it mean you do not have access to that bucke or check the access constraint again.
You can also manually copy the files to S3 by downloading the software called "CloudBerry Exlorer for Amazon S3".
Just download and provide the access key and see whether you have access to the bucket or not.

Comment: I am able to manually upload the files on S3.But when I do  the same from the job ,it gives error.I want to automate one process.